# Trying to display large bitmap images in a RecyclerView Android displays an error setDataSource failed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to load images on a RecyclerView using Glide, but I keep getting an error, Glide failed to load the resource even when the image URL seems to be there and when I click on the URL I can view the image.

Here is my FiltersViewHolder code;

```
public class FiltersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public static String PHOTO_URL="";
    private Context context;
    TrendingFilters trendingFilters;
    @BindView(R.id.filters_image)
    ImageView filtersImage;


    public FiltersViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
```

Here I try to bind the images to the ImageView using Glide;

```
    public void bind(final TrendingFilters trendingFilters) {
        this.trendingFilters = trendingFilters;
        DiskCacheStrategy strategy = DiskCacheStrategy.NONE;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.filters_image, options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        Log.e("Bitmap", imageHeight + "" + imageWidth);
        String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        if(trendingFilters.getEmbedUrl() != null) {
            GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(trendingFilters.getEmbedUrl()))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.fox_face_mesh_texture)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(strategy))
                    .fitCenter()
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .into(filtersImage);
            filtersImage.setImageBitmap(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(), R.id.filters_image, 100, 100));
            PHOTO_URL = trendingFilters.getEmbedUrl();
        }else{

        }
        itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item clicked: " + trendingFilters.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }
```

Here’s a method to calculate a sample size value that is a power of two based on a target width and height:

```
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

This method makes it easy to load a bitmap of arbitrarily large size into an ImageView that displays a  100x100 pixel thumbnail, as shown in the following example code:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.filters_image)
    public void onViewClicked() {
    }
}
```

And the error on the logcat is as follows;

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://www.svrf.com/classic/embed/vr/1041219 with size [1141x284]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ContentLengthInputStream->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

Comment: use glide listeners to see exactly if your bitmap is null or not to make sure if the problem is caused by url and inform us of the result?(if your url is http and not https dont forget to add cleartext tag to the manifest)